# Synchronized ArrayList as static method parameter

Tags: java, android, synchronized

I have a method like this:

```
public static void normalizeMessages(ArrayList<Message> messages){
    synchronized (messages) {
        Collections.sort(messages, new Comparator<Message>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Message lhs, Message rhs) {
                return lhs.getId().compareTo(rhs.getId());
            }
        });
    }
    // do something with sorted list
}
```

My `ArrayList` can be modified (add, remove items) in somewhere from other threads, so I have to use `synchronized`. 
But I'm not sure that this way is correct, because I got a warning from `Android studio`: **Synchronization on method parameter 'messages'** 
Do I need to use `Collections.synchronizedList` for this `ArrayList` & use `synchronized` in any codes modify this list?

Comment: `synchronized` should be done on a common  'monitor' object. Each thread would have their own copy of method parameters (i.e. 'messages'). So, the monitor object is not common between the threads. This would, in effect, lose the benefit of synchronization.

Comment: @SiddharthaGhosh So I have to synchronized the caller of this method?

Comment: This is not really true. If all your threads are working withe the *same* list, then for sure you could use that list to also synchronize on.

Comment: @GhostCat ok, so do you have any suggestion for this case?

Comment: Not really. I guess I would study Android study to see if it gives any kind of explanation why they consider this worth a warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare this `message` parameter as global variable in the class and make it `volatile`.Hence all thread will have the same copy of your object.So it will give the benefit of `synchronization`.

Comment: Sorry, but that is not helpful. The point of synchronizing on a data structure is to prevent multiple threads making updates to it at the same time. Such races can lead to all sorts of data corruption and inconsistencies. Making an object volatile does not at all help with that part!